# How can I edit a Python library containing .cpython files?

Tags: python, numpy, lxml, cpython

My problem is simple : I want to modify some classical Python packages (like `numpy` or `lxml`) to have them lighter and only keep what is useful to a specifical application. However, I can't find a way to edit some of the files contained in the library as it seems they are compiled files (extension : `file.cpython-37m_64-linux-gnu.so`).

How should I proceed to edit those files if I need to please ?

Comment: Those aren't ``.cpython`` files, those are [``.so`` files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#File_naming) – compiled dynamically linked library files. You *don't* edit these files. If anything you edit their source and recompile them, though picking the correct parts out of ``numpy`` and friends is not a simple task.

Comment: Identifying the parts of a package like `numpy` that you don't need will require, I think, an indepth knowledge of the package.  There might a few submodules, like `recfunctions`, `matrix` and `ma` that you could omit, but I suspect they contribute little to the overall size.  Almost anything marked as `.so` will be central to the `numpy` functionality.

Comment: I see, so if I get it right, we're not supposed to edit those packages ? I mean, it doesn't seem they are made to be. Maybe someone knows where I can find the sources of the .so files then ? Thx !!

Comment: Most packages are open source. For example, [numpy is on GitHub](https://github.com/numpy/numpy).